# What does `std::kill_dependency` do, and why would I want to use it?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-model, c++11

I've been reading about the new C++11 memory model and I've come upon the `std::kill_dependency` function (§29.3/14-15). I'm struggling to understand why I would ever want to use it.

I found an example in the [N2664 proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2664.htm#selective) but it didn't help much.

It starts by showing code without `std::kill_dependency`. Here, the first line carries a dependency into the second, which carries a dependency into the indexing operation, and then carries a dependency into the `do_something_with` function.

```
r1 = x.load(memory_order_consume);
r2 = r1->index;
do_something_with(a[r2]);
```

There is further example that uses `std::kill_dependency` to break the dependency between the second line and the indexing.

```
r1 = x.load(memory_order_consume);
r2 = r1->index;
do_something_with(a[std::kill_dependency(r2)]);
```

As far as I can tell, this means that the indexing and the call to `do_something_with` are not dependency ordered before the second line. According to N2664:

> This allows the compiler to reorder the call to `do_something_with`, for example, by performing speculative optimizations that predict the value of `a[r2]`.

In order to make the call to `do_something_with` the value `a[r2]` is needed. If, hypothetically, the compiler "knows" that the array is filled with zeros, it can optimize that call to `do_something_with(0);` and reorder this call relative to the other two instructions as it pleases. It could produce any of:

```
// 1
r1 = x.load(memory_order_consume);
r2 = r1->index;
do_something_with(0);
// 2
r1 = x.load(memory_order_consume);
do_something_with(0);
r2 = r1->index;
// 3
do_something_with(0);
r1 = x.load(memory_order_consume);
r2 = r1->index;
```

Is my understanding correct?

If `do_something_with` synchronizes with another thread by some other means, what does this mean with respect to the ordering of the `x.load` call and this other thread?

Assuming my understading is correct, there's still one thing that bugs me: when I'm writing code, what reasons would lead me to choose to kill a dependency?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The purpose of memory_order_consume is to ensure the compiler does not do certain unfortunate optimizations that may break lockless algorithms. For example, consider this code:

```
int t;
volatile int a, b;

t = *x;
a = t;
b = t;
```

A conforming compiler may transform this into:

```
a = *x;
b = *x;
```

Thus, a may not equal b. It may also do:

```
t2 = *x;
// use t2 somewhere
// later
t = *x;
a = t2;
b = t;
```

By using `load(memory_order_consume)`, we require that uses of the value being loaded not be moved prior to the point of use. In other words,

```
t = x.load(memory_order_consume);
a = t;
b = t;
assert(a == b); // always true
```

The standard document considers a case where you may only be interested in ordering certain fields of a structure. The example is:

```
r1 = x.load(memory_order_consume);
r2 = r1->index;
do_something_with(a[std::kill_dependency(r2)]);
```

This instructs the compiler that it is allowed to, effectively, do this:

```
predicted_r2 = x->index; // unordered load
r1 = x; // ordered load
r2 = r1->index;
do_something_with(a[predicted_r2]); // may be faster than waiting for r2's value to be available
```

Or even this:

```
predicted_r2 = x->index; // unordered load
predicted_a  = a[predicted_r2]; // get the CPU loading it early on
r1 = x; // ordered load
r2 = r1->index; // ordered load
do_something_with(predicted_a);
```

If the compiler knows that `do_something_with` won't change the result of the loads for r1 or r2, then it can even hoist it all the way up:

```
do_something_with(a[x->index]); // completely unordered
r1 = x; // ordered
r2 = r1->index; // ordered
```

This allows the compiler a little more freedom in its optimization.

Comment: Hmm, so kill_dependency is that kind of thing you won't normally use up front. You use it on critical parts of the code that end up needing to squeeze some extra speed. The tradeoff is that you risk introducing subtle threading bugs if you do it carelessly. Am I right?

Comment: Pretty much, although I'd point out that the moment you're using lockless algorithms you're already dealing with subtle bugs if you take one wrong step

Comment: Wow! good answer.  I was wondering if anyone really understood all the new memory ordering stuff in C++11's memory model.  It looks like you do.

Comment: "_A conforming compiler may transform this into:_" Hug? The whole point of `volatile` is to forbid that!

Comment: @curiousguy, Nope! the compiler can't optimize away the stores into the volatile variable, but it can do _whatever the heck it wants_ with the loads from `t`

Comment: "_it can do whatever the heck it wants with the loads from t_" OK. My point is: `b = a;` cannot be "optimised" (transformed, pessimized) in any way.

Comment: @curiousguy, that is true, and it is also not relevant here - none of my examples assign from volatile to volatile. The use of volatile here is just to simplify the example - the compiler can do some even nastier tricks if `a` and `b` aren't volatile.

Comment: For example, consider this code: 

int t;
volatile int a, b;

t = *x;
a = t;
b = a;
 !

Comment: @curiousguy, ah, missed that. Changed to `b=t;`

Comment: Is ```assert(a == b); // always true``` actually guaranteed by the standard? The wording from the proposal is "In particular, if the compiler is able to optimize a member of a dependency tree to a constant, then the compiler must either produce code that preserves the dependency tree or emit a memory barrier appropriate to the target architecture." So, if the compiler decides to do e.g. ```a=*x; b=*x``` and just add barriers, is a==b still certain?

Comment: The phrase "uses of the value being loaded not be moved prior to the point of use" does not make any sense to me. That says that the use of t will not be moved prior to itself. Ie, a = t won't be moved above a = t. That is rather trivial. Can you rephrase this so it makes sense?

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the other answer, I will point out that Scott Meyers, one of the definitive leaders in the C++ community, bashed memory_order_consume pretty strongly.  He basically said that he believed it had no place in the standard.  He said there are two cases where memory_order_consume has any effect:

- Exotic architectures designed to support 1024+ core shared memory machines.
- The DEC Alpha

Yes, once again, the DEC Alpha finds its way into infamy by using an optimization not seen in any other chip until many years later on absurdly specialized machines.

The particular optimization is that those processors allow one to dereference a field before actually getting the address of that field (i.e. it can look up x->y BEFORE it even looks up x, using a predicted value of x).  It then goes back and determines whether x was the value it expected it to be.  On success, it saved time.  On failure, it has to go back and get x->y again.

Memory_order_consume tells the compiler/architecture that these operations have to happen in order.  However, in the most useful case, one will end up wanting to do (x->y.z), where z doesn't change.  memory_order_consume would force the compiler to keep x y and z in order.  kill_dependency(x->y).z tells the compiler/architecture that it may resume doing such nefarious reorderings.

99.999% of developers will probably never work on a platform where this feature is required (or has any effect at all).

Comment: Has Scott Meyers written any standards proposals or core or library issues?

Comment: Here in 2016 I'd like to point out that 1,024 core machines are going to be on your desktop in 2020. If you're writing CUDA / OpenCL they *already are*.

Comment: @ZanLynx True, though the shared memory machines I mention are still rather exotic.  Most of the desktop machines that are piling on the cores take great care to avoid forcing developers to pay such detailed attention to which core has which memory.  The cases I am thinking of where I am calling them "exotic" are cases where programmers are acutely aware of the topology of the interconnects between processors, because the transfer of data between processors is as important or more important than the calculations.

Comment: Starting 2017, IBM POWER9 is the new DEC Alpha of weak memory ordering. The problem does exist.

Answer (score 4):

The usual use case of `kill_dependency` arises from the following. Suppose you want to do atomic updates to a nontrivial shared data structure. A typical way to do this is to nonatomically create some new data and to atomically swing a pointer from the data structure to the new data. Once you do this, you are not going to change the new data until you have swung the pointer away from it to something else (and waited for all readers to vacate). This paradigm is widely used, e.g. read-copy-update in the Linux kernel.

Now, suppose the reader reads the pointer, reads the new data, and comes back later and reads the pointer again, finding that the pointer hasn't changed. The hardware can't tell that the pointer hasn't been updated again, so by `consume` semantics he can't use a cached copy of the data but has to read it again from memory. (Or to think of it another way, the hardware and compiler can't speculatively move the read of the data up before the read of the pointer.)

This is where `kill_dependency` comes to the rescue. By wrapping the pointer in a `kill_dependency`, you create a value that will no longer propagate dependency, allowing accesses through the pointer to  use the cached copy of the new data.

Comment: This seems the perfect answer to the asked question. Thanks!