# C++11: the difference between memory_order_relaxed and memory_order_consume

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-model, stdatomic

I am now learning [C++11 memory order model](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) and would like to understand the difference between `memory_order_relaxed` and `memory_order_consume`.

To be specific, I am looking for a simple example where one cannot replace `memory_order_consume` with `memory_order_relaxed`.

There is an excellent [post](http://preshing.com/20140709/the-purpose-of-memory_order_consume-in-cpp11/) which elaborates on a simple yet very illustrative example where `memory_order_consume` can be applied. Below is literal copy-paste.

Example:

```cpp
atomic<int*> Guard(nullptr);
int Payload = 0;
```

Producer:

```cpp
Payload = 42;
Guard.store(&Payload, memory_order_release);
```

Consumer:

```cpp
g = Guard.load(memory_order_consume);
if (g != nullptr)
    p = *g;
```

My question consists of two parts:

1. Can one replace `memory_order_consume` with `memory_order_relaxed` in the example above?
2. Can one suggest a similar example where `memory_order_consume` cannot be replaced with `memory_order_relaxed`?

Comment: "Consume" is deprecated in C++17 because essentially nobody has been able to implement it in any way that's better than "acquire". Think of "consume" as a (restricted) version of "acquire".

Comment: I have a [possibly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609964/how-do-acquire-and-consume-memory-orders-differ-and-when-is-consume-prefe) here that might interest you.

Comment: @KerrekSB Consume is a contaminant, like a qualifier; a bit like "pointer to volatile" (you can't get rid of volatile). Well, you can get rid of the taint, but at the price of the acquire barrier that we try to avoid. Maybe it should have been introduced as another qualifier, or to avoid "overloading" the type system, as a template "quasi type qualifier".

Answer (score 28):

### Question 1

No.
`memory_order_relaxed` imposes no memory order at all:

> Relaxed operation: there are no synchronization or ordering constraints, only atomicity is required of this operation.

While `memory_order_consume` imposes memory ordering on data dependent reads (on the current thread)

> A load operation with this memory order performs a consume operation on the affected memory location: no reads in the current thread dependent on the value currently loaded can be reordered before this load.

**Edit**

In general `memory_order_seq_cst` is stronger `memory_order_acq_rel` is stronger `memory_ordering_relaxed`.
This is like having a Elevator A that can lift 800 Kg Elevator C that lifts 100Kg.
Now if you had the power to magically change Elevator A into Elevator C, what would happen if the former was filled with 10 average-weighting people?
That would be bad.

To see what could go wrong with the code exactly, consider the example on your question:

```
Thread A                                   Thread B
Payload = 42;                              g = Guard.load(memory_order_consume);
Guard.store(1, memory_order_release);      if (g != 0)
                                               p = Payload;
```

This snippet are intended to be looped, there is no synchronization, only ordering, between the two threads.

With `memory_order_relaxed`, and assuming that a natural word load/store is atomic, the code would be equivalent to

```
Thread A                                   Thread B
Payload = 42;                              g = Guard
Guard = 1                                  if (g != 0)
                                               p = Payload;
```

From a CPU point of view on Thread A there are two stores to two separate addresses, so if `Guard` is "closer" to the CPU (meaning the store will complete faster) from another processor it seems that Thread A is perfoming

```
Thread A
Guard = 1
Payload = 42
```

And this order of execution is possible

```
Thread A   Guard = 1
Thread B   g = Guard
Thread B   if (g != nullptr) p = Payload
Thread A   Payload = 42
```

And that's bad, since Thread B read a **non updated value of Payload**.

It could seems however that in Thread B the synchronization would be useless since the CPU won't do a reorder like

```
Thread B
if (g != 0) p = Payload;
g = Guard
```

But it actually will.

From its perspective there are two unrelated load, it is true that one is on a dependent data path but the CPU can still speculatively do the load:

```
Thread B
hidden_tmp = Payload;
g = Guard
if (g != 0) p = hidden_tmp
```

That may generate the sequence

```
Thread B   hidden_tmp = Payload;
Thread A   Payload = 42;
Thread A   Guard = 1;
Thread B   g = Guard
Thread B   if (g != 0) p = hidden_tmp
```

Whoops.

### Question 2

In general that can never be done.
You can replace `memory_order_acquire` with `memory_order_consume` when you are going to generate an address dependency between the loaded value and the value(s) whose access need to be ordered.

---

To understand `memory_order_relaxed` we can take the ARM architecture as a reference.
The ARM Architecture mandates only a *weak memory ordering* meaning that in general the loads and stores of a program can be executed in **any** order.

```
str r0, [r2]
str r0, [r3]
```

In the snippet above the store to `[r3]` can be observed, externally, before the store to `[r2]`<sup>1</sup>.

However the CPU doesn't go as far as the Alpha CPU and imposes [two kinds of dependencies](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0321a/BIHHIAEC.html): **address dependency**, when a value load from memory is used to compute the address of another load/store, and **control dependency**, when a value load from memory is used to compute the control flags of another load/store.

In the presence of such dependency the ordering of two memory operations is guaranteed to be [visible in program order](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0321a/BIHHIAEC.html):

> If there is an address dependency then the two memory accesses are observed in program order.

So, while a `memory_order_acquire` would generate a memory barrier, with `memory_order_consume` you are telling the compiler that the way you'll use the loaded value will generate an address dependency and so it can, if relevant to the architecture, exploit this fact and omit a memory barrier.

---

<sup>1</sup> If `r2` is the address of a synchronization object, that's bad.

Comment: Thank you @Margaret. Your answer to the first questions was `No`. Could you please say what might happen if we use `memory_order_relaxed` in the particular example above? I cannot imagine why it shouldn't work.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer.

Although, I still wanna argue with your reasoning :-)
Please, don't take me wrong. I'm just learning things and wanna talk to experienced people like you.

1.
> ... it seems that Thread A is perfoming
> Thread A
> Guard = 1
> Payload = 42

This cannot happen as `memory_order_release` prevents it from happening.

2.
> .. but the CPU can still speculatively do the load

This cannot happen as well since it would imply `nullptr` de-reference since `g` can be `nullptr`

Comment: @TruLa, You were talking about using `memory_order_relaxed`, that's what would happen (on thread A and thread B) using it and that's **why** `memory_order_release` is used instead on Thread A. Regarding Thread B, the CPU has no problem executing a load from a nullptr, at worst you'll end up with an exception instead of an old value of `Payload`. Still something that **wouldn't happend** on strong ordered architectures.

Comment: a) No, the question in my initial post was whether one can replace `mem_order_consume` with `mem_order_relaxed`. This is obviously not equivalent to both threads using `mem_order_relaxed`. Thread A should still use `mem_order_release`.

Comment: b) I am very surprised that `if (g != nullptr) p = *g;` in the example above can lead to page fault or SEGFAULT. I don't believe that :-)

Comment: @TruLa release without a matching consume/acquire does nothing. If you're familiar with mutex, consider what happens if one thread releases a mutex, and the other decides to skip acquire and just access the critical section blindly.

Also, while this answer is good, it could use mentioning that all these memory orders are for the optimizer as much as the CPU. The compilers can reorder/coalesce/speculate memory accesses freely unless constrained by memory orderings, even in a single-core environment.

Comment: @Trula, a) From your first comment "Could you please say what might happen if we use memory_order_relaxed in the particular example above?" b) AFAIK only the Alpha reorder even on presence of address dependencies. The page you linked does a **very good** job explaining these concept. Please remember **this is not a chat**.  @ Cubbi, Agree, though in single-core environment there's no external observer and most (if not all) of this won't apply.

Answer (score 9):

> Can one replace `memory_order_consume` with `memory_order_relaxed` in the example above?

**Safely in ISO C++: no.**

**In *practice* on most implementations for most ISAs, often yes**.  It will normally compile to asm with a data dependency between the first load result and the 2nd load's address, and most ISAs do guarantee that ordering.  (This is the HW feature `consume` was intended to expose).

But since C++11's design for `consume` was impractical for compilers to implement, they all just gave up and strengthen it to `acquire`, requiring a memory barrier on most weakly-ordered ISAs.  (e.g. POWER or ARM, but not x86).

So in real life, to get that juicy performance for reading things that nearly never change, some real code (like RCU) does actually use `relaxed` carefully, in ways that we hope won't get optimized into something unsafe.  See Paul E. McKenney's CppCon 2016 talk: [C++ Atomics: The Sad Story of memory_order_consume: A Happy Ending At Last?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrNQKpOypqU&index=44&list=PLHTh1InhhwT75gykhs7pqcR_uSiG601oh) about how Linux uses this to make the read side of RCU very very cheap, with no barriers.  (In kernel they just use `volatile` instead of `_Atomic` with `memory_order_relaxed`, but those compile essentially the same for pure-load or pure-store.)

By being careful about how you use `consume`, and knowing how compilers normally compile code, it's possible to get known compilers like gcc and clang to fairly reliably emit safe/correct and *efficient* asm for known targets like x86, ARM, and POWER that are known to do dependency ordering in hardware.

(x86 does `acquire` in hardware for you so if you only cared about x86 you'd be gaining nothing from using `relaxed` over `consume` or `acquire`.)

> Can one suggest a similar example where `memory_order_consume` cannot be replaced with `memory_order_relaxed`?

DEC Alpha AXP doesn't guarantee dependency ordering in HW, and a few Alpha microarchitectures really could violate causality by loading a `*g` value older than `g`.  See [Dependent loads reordering in CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115634/dependent-loads-reordering-in-cpu) and also [Memory order consume usage in C11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55741148/memory-order-consume-usage-in-c11) for a quote from Linus Torvalds about how only a few Alpha machines could actually do this.

**Or for any ISA, it can break at compile time if the compiler breaks the data dependency with a control dependency.**  e.g. if the compiler has some reason to think that `g` will have a certain value, it's allowed to transform to `p = *g` into code like

```
    if (g == expected_address)
        p = *expected_address;
    else
        p = *g;
```

Real CPUs use branch prediction so instructions after a branch can execute even if the `g.load()` hasn't finished yet.  So `p = *expected_address` can execute with no data dependency on `g`.

Weakly-ordered ISAs that do document their dependency ordering guarantees (POWER, ARM, etc.) don't guarantee it across branches, only true *data* dependencies.  (It would be fine if both sides of the branch used `*g`.)

This might not be something compilers are likely to do, but C++ `consume` guarantees that even `array[foo.load(consume) & 1]` is dependency-ordered after the load.  With only 2 possible values, it's more plausible that the compiler would branch.

(Or in your example, if `atomic<int*> Guard(nullptr);` is `static` and its address doesn't escape the compilation unit, **then the compiler might see that the only 2 values it can ever have are `nullptr` or `&Payload`**, and thus if it's non-null then it must be Payload.  So yes this optimization actually is plausible in your case, for `mo_relaxed`.  I think current gcc / clang probably won't ever make any assumptions about a value loaded from an atomic (like they treat `volatile`) so you're probably safe in practice.  This might change once C++ gets a way to make it safe for compilers to optimize atomics.  [Can and does the compiler optimize out two atomic loads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820539/can-and-does-the-compiler-optimize-out-two-atomic-loads))

---

**In fact, ISO C++ `consume` even guarantees dependency ordering for `int dep = foo.load(consume); dep -= dep;  p = array[dep];`**  You can use this to get dependency ordering after branching on a flag, for example, even after reducing the dependency to a value that's known at compile time<sup>1</sup>.  In this case zero.

But compilers look for cases where a variable is reduced to only 1 possible value, and will turn that `p = array[dep]` into `p = array[0]`, removing the dependency on the load.  (This is the kind of dependency tracking to figure out when it was or wasn't safe to do normal optimizations that made `consume` nearly impossible to implement safely without gimping the compiler everywhere.  The carries_dependency and kill_dependency stuff might have limited this to function boundaries, but it still ended up being too hard.)

Footnote 1: This is why ISAs like ARM aren't even *allowed* to special case `eor r0, r0` as a dependency-breaking zeroing idiom [the way x86 does for `xor eax,eax`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and/33668295#33668295).  The asm rules do guarantee it's safe to do something like this *in asm*.  (And fixed-instruction-width ISAs have no use for xor-zeroing anyway; `mov r0, #0` is the same size.)  The problem is getting compilers to emit asm with a dependency that's only required by consume, without doing any of their usual transformations that avoid data dependencies and create instruction-level parallelism for out-of-order execution to find and exploit.

---

**See also [P0371R1: Temporarily discourage memory_order_consume](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0371r1.html) and other C++ wg21 documents linked from that about why consume is discouraged.**

> The difficulties appear to stem both from the high implementation complexity, from the fact that the current definition uses a fairly general definition of "dependency", thus requiring frequent and inconvenient use of the `kill_dependency` call, and from the frequent need for `[[carries_dependency]]` annotations.  Details can be found in e.g. [P0098R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0098r0.pdf).

Comment: A programmer reading `int tmp = foo.load(consume); tmp -= tmp;  p = array[tmp];` for the first time in his life might assume the author was crazy - or having fun at the expense of the reader! Until he/she understands that something important was being done...

Comment: @curiousguy: yeah, any real use-case would hopefully be commented.  I changed the var name to `dep` to highlight its purpose.