# Linux kernel memory model pointer access and dereference

Tags: linux, concurrency, parallel-processing, linux-kernel, memory-barriers

I was reading through the guide to using the various memory barriers provided by Linux and came upon the example below.

I was curious as to the reason why CPU2 will load P into Q before issuing the load of *Q or whether this is actually guaranteed to always be the case?

I do not see it explicitly stated but I assume there is a memory ordering guarantee that all writes to a pointer variable will occur before any subsequent deference of that pointer variable? Can anyone confirm this to be an accurate interpretation or provide evidence from the Linux-kernel memory model that justifies this behavior?

```
As a further example, consider this sequence of events:

        CPU 1           CPU 2
        =============== ===============
        { A == 1, B == 2, C == 3, P == &A, Q == &C }
        B = 4;          Q = P;
        P = &B;         D = *Q;

There is an obvious address dependency here, as the value loaded into D depends
on the address retrieved from P by CPU 2.  At the end of the sequence, any of
the following results are possible:

        (Q == &A) and (D == 1)
        (Q == &B) and (D == 2)
        (Q == &B) and (D == 4)

Note that CPU 2 will never try and load C into D because the CPU will load P
into Q before issuing the load of *Q.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux kernel with `volatile` is essentially the same as ISO C with `memory_order_relaxed`. (Or stronger because compile-time reordering of `volatile` operations wrt. each other isn't allowed even to different addresses.)  (In [Linux kernel code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/asm-generic/rwonce.h#L47) this would be `WRITE_ONCE(B, 4);` and so on, unless you actually declared the shared variables as `volatile`.)

Within the same thread, sequencing and coherence rules apply, so `shared = 1;`  `tmp = shared` is guaranteed to read `1` or some later value in the modification order of `shared`.

Except it's even simpler in this case: **`Q` isn't touched by CPU 1 in this example, so it's not a shared variable, it's effectively local to CPU 2**.  The as-if rules of compiler optimization and out-of-order execution require preserving single-threaded correctness, like that variables have their new values after we write them.

Dereferencing an atomic pointer involve reading it into a temporary (a register on all(?) current ISAs that Linux supports) and then dereferencing that temporary.  **In this case, `Q` is that temporary, despite the unclear naming convention.**

The read itself (of `Q`) is sequenced after the write (`Q = ...`) from the same thread.

---

The pointed-to data from `D = *Q;` is dependency-ordered after the read of `Q`, like C/C++ `memory_order_consume`, except on DEC Alpha AXP.  All other ISAs that Linux runs on have hardware memory-dependency ordering, and a compiler can't plausibly break this code by knowing there's only one possible value for `Q` and using a constant for that which doesn't have a data dependency on the `P` load result.  Or a branch (control dependencies can be speculated past, unlike data dependencies).

But we can still read `(Q == &B) && (D == 2)` because CPU 1 didn't do a [release store](https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/).  If it had, then even though CPU 2 didn't do an acquire load, the data dependency through the address will stop any real-world CPU from loading from `*Q` until after it knows the address from `Q`.

If you want to rely on this in Linux kernel code, you should use `smp_read_barrier_depends()` between `Q = P` and `*Q`.  It's a no-op on everything except Alpha.

- [Memory order consume usage in C11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55741148/memory-order-consume-usage-in-c11)
- [C++11: the difference between memory_order_relaxed and memory_order_consume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280633/c11-the-difference-between-memory-order-relaxed-and-memory-order-consume)
- Paul E. McKenney's CppCon 2016 talk: [C++ Atomics: The Sad Story of `memory_order_consume`: A Happy Ending At Last?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrNQKpOypqU&index=44&list=PLHTh1InhhwT75gykhs7pqcR_uSiG601oh) - he describes how Linux effectively uses `relaxed` and avoids doing stuff like `tmp = shared; array[tmp - tmp]` as a way to get one load ordered after another because compilers will optimize that to a constant `0` with no dependency.

  (That's why C++'s `memory_order_consume` had to exist, because it *does* let you do stuff like that with formal guarantees; on real ISAs like AArch64, compilers would have to emit asm that generates a `0` with a data dependency on `tmp`, e.g. with a `sub` or `xor` instruction.  Fun fact, non-x86 CPUs aren't even *allowed* to optimize xor-zeroing of registers because their ISA rules say `xor` and `sub` carry a dependency.  Anyway, that's also why `memory_order_consume` proved so hard to support correctly, so compilers gave up and promoted `consume` to `acquire` instead of possibly having their optimizer break code like this.  Linux kernel code *can* rely on stuff like "we know what we're doing well enough with a limited set of compilers that we can write code that compilers shouldn't optimize in ways that breaks `consume`")

Comment: So the intra-thread data dependency is what guarantees the load from P occurs prior to the read from Q solely in CPU2. Use of volatile would also result in visibility guarantee of write to P being read by CPU 2 in program order of CPU 1 (write to B ordered before write to P). Am I interpreting that correctly?

Comment: @DarnocEloc: No, `volatile P` guarantees visibility without ordering, and is necessary for shared variables at all (to avoid weird effects or obvious total breakage: https://lwn.net/Articles/793253/).  My answer is already assuming `volatile int *P` so accesses to it are like `P.store(val, memory_order_relaxed)` or `P.load(memory_order_relaxed)`.  i.e. I'm assuming that these assignments are pseudo-code for safe/correct atomic relaxed accesses to any variables that are shared.

Comment: If the memory_order_relaxed constraint on the atomic operations is "upgraded" to memory_order_consume or higher, then my prior statement would be accurate since the load carries a dependency into both operations of CPU 2, guaranteeing visibility and ordering, correct? I understand memory_order_consume is discouraged but wanted to clarify that this instance would be a valid use case. I understand volatile only imposes intra-thread ordering and inter-thread visibility without ordering, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @DarnocEloc: You seemed to be saying that CPU 2 would be guaranteed to see `B == 4` if it sees `P == &B`.  Yes this requires `consume` (or `relaxed` that compiles to good asm) on the read side, but it *also* requires `release` on the writer side which we *don't* have.  On CPUs with weak memory models (unlike x86 and SPARC-TSO), stores can commit out of order from the store buffer, so even the compile-time ordering between two `volatile` stores doesn't save us.  (Except on x86 and SPARC-TSO where StoreStore ordering is guaranteed.)  The `(Q == &B) and (D == 2)` result is a real possibility.

Comment: In a nutshell, my interpretation is, with relaxed ordering (memory_order_relaxed), all 3 results are possible. However, with release-consume ordering or higher, only (Q == &B) and (D == 4) is possible.

Comment: @DarnocEloc: `volatile` alone doesn't give you `release` stores.  `release`-`consume` also still allows `(Q == &A) and (D == 1)` - simple interleaving (like allowed with `seq_cst`) can explain that: both statements from CPU 2 run before either from CPU 1 affect cache or even run at all.  release-consume would rule out `(Q == &B) and (D == 2)`

Comment: So, on strongly-ordered architectures with release-store semantics available, (Q == &A) and (D == 1) and (Q == &B) and (D == 4) are possible with release-consume or stricter ordering. On weakly ordered systems, memory fence or special CPU load instructions would be required to prevent (Q == &B) and (D == 2). This might be out of scope, but, in both cases semaphore and cv would be necessary to prevent  (Q == &A) and (D == 1).

Comment: @DarnocEloc:  Correct on both counts.  Or a spin-wait loop, or in user-space a `futex` to wait for `P` to change.  In C++ terms, `P.wait(&A)` to wait for it to not be pointing to `A` anymore.  (And then CPU 1 would have to do `P.notify_all()` after storing to it, after somehow knowing that a waiting thread existed.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/77968202/linux-kernel-memory-model-hardware-memory-models-and-language-memory-models Created this discussion thread from a follow-up question I wanted to ask, feel free to contribute.