# Are C++11 compilers allowed to introduce additional loads of atomic variables?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, memory-model

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7152246/21475), bdonlan states that code similar to the following:

```
int t;
volatile int a, b;

t = x;
a = t;
b = t;
```

may be transformed by the compiler into:

```
a = x;
b = x;
```

My question is, is this still allowed if `x` is an atomic variable with relaxed loads, as in the following?

```
atomic<int> x;

int t;
volatile int a, b;

t = x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
a = t;
b = t;
assert(a == b);    // Will this hold?
```

As the title says, are C++11 compilers allowed to introduce additional loads of atomic variables? What about additional stores?

Comment: The compiler is allowed to do anything under the as-if rule.  The compiler would have to show that no other thread could be accessing the same variable

Comment: @Vaughn: Hmm, then does that mean that the first example from bdonlan's answer can't happen? And, I thought the as-if rule only applied to individual threads? (Am I mistaken?) Compilers continually surprise me!

Comment: @Cameron: If another thread modified the non-atomic `x` value, reading from it would invoke undefined behavior on this thread, since this thread doesn't synchronize with it. So you can get whatever, including the behavior from the linked answer.

Comment: @Nicol: Ah, I see, thanks. But then what about the second example? The standard says that relaxed atomic operations are not synchronization operations -- does that have any bearing here?

Comment: @Cameron _The standard says that relaxed atomic operations are not synchronization operations_ - Right, but that only affects the value written to `t`. Whatever that value will be, you can be sure that the very same value will get written to both `a` and `b` (assuming that `a`, `b` and `t` are only ever accessed by the same thread)

Comment: @Vaughn: Could you submit your comment as an answer?

Comment: What is `x` in that code?

Comment: @Cameron "_the as-if rule only applied to individual threads_" **There is special language no rule called the as if rule.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is allowed to do anything under the as-if rule, but to load the same memory location twice, the compiler would have to show that no other thread could be accessing the same variable.  Either way, you are guaranteed that `a==b` in your example.